# How can I implement JSON file into a drop down list for countries in a validation form?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, controller

I tried with this code, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
public ActionResult Getcountries()
{
    var webClient = new WebClient();
    var json = webClient.DownloadString(@"C:\Users\kristijanm\source\repos\contactForm\contactForm\data\Countries.json");
    var CountryL = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CountriesModel>(json);
    return View(CountryL);
}
```

Here is my Model:

```
 public class CountriesModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: pls show your CountriesModel and view too

Comment: it's still not implemented in the view.